# HTML5 - drag&drop a JPG and receive its width

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop

I want to receive the width of a JPG after dragging it into the browser window. The strange thing is, sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes a width of zero is returned.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8m3s/)

```
document.body.addEventListener('drop', function ( e ) 
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    reader.readAsDataURL( file );
    reader.onloadend = function()
    {
        var source = this.result;
        var currentImg = new Image();
        currentImg.src = source;    

        var someDiv = document.createElement("div");
        someDiv.innerHTML = '<li>'+currentImg.width+'</li>';

        document.getElementById("logs").appendChild(someDiv);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you probably get width before the image is loaded. 
Put some code like this and you works correctly.

```
...
var currentImg = new Image();
currentImg.onload = function() {
    var someDiv = document.createElement("div");
    someDiv.innerHTML = '<li>'+currentImg.width+'</li>';
    document.getElementById("logs").appendChild(someDiv);
}
currentImg.src = source;   
...
```

put the onload before setting the sorce because onload is a callback function.